# Excel VBA - Using .ModifyAppliesTo and Run-Time Error 1004 (Problem Trying To Insert A String That Is Too Long?)

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am very new to coding with Excel VBA and am currently stuck trying to get Excel to conditionally format my desired cells based on a formula. I am using the property .ModifyAppliesToRange. My code used works fine if I use a short example string such as "D5,D6,D7,D8". What I want to do is insert a much bigger string such as:

"=D5,N5,X5,AH5,J6,T6,AD6,F7,P7,Z7,AJ7,L8,V8,AF8,H9,R9,AB9,D10,N10,X10,AH10,J11,T11,AD11,F12,P12,Z12,AJ12,L13,V13,AF13,H14,R14,AB14,D15,N15,X15,AH15,J16,T16,AD16,F17,P17,Z17,AJ17,L18,V18,AF18,H19,R19,AB19,D20,N20,X20,AH20,J21,T21,AD21,F22,P22,Z22,AJ22,L23,V23,AF23,H24,R24,AB24,D25,N25,X25,AH25,J26,T26,AD26,F27,P27,Z27,AJ27,L28,V28,AF28,H29,R29,AB29,D30,N30,X30,AH30,J31,T31,AD31,F32,P32,Z32,AJ32,L33,V33,AF33,H34,R34,AB34,D35,N35,X35,AH35,J36,T36,AD36,F37,P37,Z37,AJ37,L38,V38,AF38,H39,R39,AB39,D40,N40,X40,AH40,J41,T41,AD41,F42,P42,Z42,AJ42,L43,V43,AF43,H44,R44,AB44,D45,N45,X45,AH45,J46,T46,AD46,F47,P47,Z47,AJ47,L48,V48,AF48,H49,R49,AB49,D50,N50,X50,AH50,J51,T51,AD51,F52,P52,Z52,AJ52,L53,V53,AF53,H54,R54,AB54"

However, when the string gets longer in length the program crashes and I get the following error:

> "Run-time error 1004: Method 'Range of object'_Global failed.

Below is my code (apologies it is only the last few lines that are directly relevant):

```
'This code does the conditional formatting for the target spreadsheet!
Dim targetFile As String
Dim targetSheet As String
Dim targetTestCell As String
Dim targetTestSheet As String
Dim targetTestWorkbook As String
Dim formulaAddMe As String
Dim exampleInsert As String

targetFile = Range("D20").Value
targetSheet = Range("D21").Value
firstCell = Range("D17") & Range("D18")
targetTestCell = Range("AD13").Value
targetTestWorkbook = Range("C32").Value
targetTestSheet = Range("C33").Value

    Windows(targetFile).Activate
    Sheets(targetSheet).Select
    Range(firstCell).Select

formulaAddMe = "=[" & targetTestWorkbook & "]" & targetTestSheet & "!" & targetTestCell & "=0"



    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        formulaAddMe
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    exampleInsert = "D5,D6,D7,D8" 'this is a variable I used to check my code works - the example code works as this string is short in length
    MsgBox exampleInsert
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
    .ModifyAppliesToRange Range(exampleInsert)
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End Sub
```

After doing some experimentation and gradually making the exampleInsert string longer the .ModifyAppliesTo works until the point at which the characters for V23 are added.

```
exampleInsert = "=D5,N5,X5,AH5,J6,T6,AD6,F7,P7,Z7,AJ7,L8,V8,AF8,H9,R9,AB9,D10,N10,X10,AH10,J11,T11,AD11,F12,P12,Z12,AJ12,L13,V13,AF13,H14,R14,AB14,D15,N15,X15,AH15,J16,T16,AD16,F17,P17,Z17,AJ17,L18,V18,AF18,H19,R19,AB19,D20,N20,X20,AH20,J21,T21,AD21,F22,P22,Z22,AJ22,L23,V23"
```

So summarising to me it looks like the problem is the program is not inserting strings that are above a certain length.

Can someone please explain what do I need to do to fix my problem?  Thank you!

Comment: last address in the string - AJ ?

Comment: Code is fine. Correct the last address in the string.

Comment: Naresh - thank you for posting - I much appreciate it. Many apologies, but the string you were looking at was incorrectly pasted into Stack Overflow. I have edited the original post so my current issue is accurate, provides more information and is up to date.

Comment: It looks like Excel is only accepting the insertString of no longer than 255 characters and then it crashes. I would appreciate any suggestions as to how I can overcome this. If I paste the string manually into the Excel "Applies To" box it works fine - so presumably it is possible to find a way to insert my long string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This...

Edited your code. `Range()` does not accept string of more than 255 characters. The string is split into individual range addresses into an array and then Union of those ranges is made with a loop through the array.

```
Sub ConditionalFormatAppl()
Dim targetFile As String
Dim targetSheet As String
Dim targetTestCell As String
Dim targetTestSheet As String
Dim targetTestWorkbook As String
Dim formulaAddMe As String
Dim exampleInsert As String

targetFile = Range("D20").Value
targetSheet = Range("D21").Value
firstCell = Range("D17") & Range("D18")
targetTestCell = Range("AD13").Value
targetTestWorkbook = Range("C32").Value
targetTestSheet = Range("C33").Value

    Windows(targetFile).Activate
    Sheets(targetSheet).Select
    Range(firstCell).Select

formulaAddMe = "=[" & targetTestWorkbook & "]" & targetTestSheet & "!" & targetTestCell & "=0"
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        formulaAddMe
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    exampleInsert = "D5,N5,X5,AH5,J6,T6,AD6,F7,P7,Z7,AJ7,L8,V8,AF8,H9,R9,AB9,D10,N10," & _
            "X10,AH10,J11,T11,AD11,F12,P12,Z12,AJ12,L13,V13,AF13,H14,R14,AB14,D15,N15," & _
            "X15,AH15,J16,T16,AD16,F17,P17,Z17,AJ17,L18,V18,AF18,H19,R19,AB19,D20,N20," & _
            "X20,AH20,J21,T21,AD21,F22,P22,Z22,AJ22,L23,V23,AF23,H24,R24,AB24,D25,N25," & _
            "X25,AH25,J26,T26,AD26,F27,P27,Z27,AJ27,L28,V28,AF28,H29,R29,AB29,D30,N30," & _
            "X30,AH30,J31,T31,AD31,F32,P32,Z32,AJ32,L33,V33,AF33,H34,R34,AB34,D35,N35," & _
            "X35,AH35,J36,T36,AD36,F37,P37,Z37,AJ37,L38,V38,AF38,H39,R39,AB39,D40,N40," & _
            "X40,AH40,J41,T41,AD41,F42,P42,Z42,AJ42,L43,V43,AF43,H44,R44,AB44,D45,N45," & _
            "X45,AH45,J46,T46,AD46,F47,P47,Z47,AJ47,L48,V48,AF48,H49,R49,AB49,D50,N50," & _
            "X50,AH50,J51,T51,AD51,F52,P52,Z52,AJ52,L53,V53,AF53,H54,R54,AB54"
    
'<<<< THIS BLOCK IS ADDED NEW START >>>>
    Dim ApplyRng As Range, i As Long, ApplyRngArr
    ApplyRngArr = Split(exampleInsert, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(ApplyRngArr)
        If ApplyRng Is Nothing Then
        Set ApplyRng = Range(ApplyRngArr(i))
        Else
        Set ApplyRng = Union(ApplyRng, Range(ApplyRngArr(i)))
        End If
    Next i
'<<<< THIS BLOCK IS ADDED NEW END >>>>
        
    MsgBox exampleInsert
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
    .ModifyAppliesToRange ApplyRng 'Resulting range of the above Union Loop
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Naresh - thank you so much! This code worked very well and answered my question. The issue that I then had was adapting the code for 10 different strings. For each new string the ApplyRng needs to be reset (or the existing ApplyRng gets included in the next string). I achieved this my making ApplyRng an array, but is it possible to do an alternative way to either clear out the the value of the ApplyRng or somehow reset it?.

Comment: @alecarmstrong Do you want to clear existing conditional formatting and apply new with the new ApplyRng that you will select from the array you mentioned?

Comment: sorry if I was not very clear. I have ten different conditional formattings. The variable exampleInsert specifies which cells have a particular conditional formatting, but  for only one of the ten conditional formattings. Hence I have looped the above code so that it can also process through the other 9 conditional formattings. The issues I hit with the above code is that ApplyRng does not get emptied at the start of each loop (so the next time the code is run in the loop the Set ApplyRng gets bigger and bigger because it includes what was in it previously.

Comment: Continuing from the above... I found a quick fix was to make ApplyRng an array i.e. Dim ApplyRng(10) because each new loop the ApplyRng(loopnumber) starts empty. So the answer to your question is I do not want to clear existing conditional formatting. Each string (i.e. exampleInsert) is a new conditional formatting. I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Oh!! ok.. I guess I got it:) So you just want to clear the ApplyRng Range before the loop. You can add `If Not ApplyRng Is Nothing Then .. Set ApplyRng = Nothing .. End If` when the loop starts. ..Try it please.

Comment: No.. I again misunderstood. After reading again, I am adding a code block to the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235721/discussion-between-naresh-and-alec-armstrong).

Comment: Yes, the If block at the start of the loop helps. Please let me know.

Comment: Naresh - thank you for your coding changes - it works! I am now trying to remove ghost images that appearing immediately after I have run my program! I hoped that removing that above array might reduce the chance of the ghost image appearing!